# Excel DNA in VB.NET error "Xcopy exited with code 3"

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, excel-dna

I am getting an error but cant find any info on what is causing it.

```
Error   6   The command 
"xcopy C:\Dev\MyProject\packages\ExcelDna.AddIn.0.33.9\tools\ExcelDna.xll" 
"C:\Dev\PlatinumXL3\PlatinumXL3\bin\x86\Debug\PlatinumXL3-AddIn.xll*" /C /Y
    exited with code 3. PlatinumXL3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was NuGet Packages. Right click your project, select 'Manage NuGet Packages' and uninstall the ExcelDna packages if there are any. Then click 'Online' on the left under 'Installed Packages' and search for 'ExcelDna'. Install those packages and it should solve your problem.